# SQL Query - Cannot convert varchar to float after bulk insert

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, type-conversion, bulkinsert

I get an error

> Error converting data type varchar to float

and I am hoping for some ideas.

I'm doing a bulk insert from a `.dat` file to a temp table and then wanting to convert the data to a float when adding it to an existing table when I get the  error.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp_Table ([Op_Base_Qty] VARCHAR(50) NULL)

BULK INSERT #Temp_Table
FROM '\\File_Path.DAT' 
WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = '|', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')

TRUNCATE TABLE [DBO].[TABLE2]

INSERT INTO [DBO].[TABLE2]([Qty])
    SELECT CAST([Op_Base_Qty] AS Float)
    FROM #Temp_Table
```

Doing troubleshooting, the values that are throwing an error have a length of 9 characters (i.e. 1,000.000 or 4,324.400). There are no nulls or text in the raw data. Thinking that the length was the problem, I've also tried decimal (18,3) with no success.

How can I convert a `varchar` with characters like 1,000.000 to a float (or any numeric)?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing the commas:

```
select convert(float,replace([Op_Base_Qty],',',''))
```

Comment: Good catch. I read the next to last line in the OP thinking they put it that way for readability.

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thanks!